# How to fetch a not so random value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, random

#### The idea

At work, we've got a task no one wants to do. So I tried making a script that randomly selects a person from an array and displays their name. However, when we have an intern, we want him/her to turn up more often than the others.

Keep in mind this is just some fooling around with code.

#### Code

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['names'])) {
    // Prepare initial array
    $names = array(
        'John Doe' => 10,
        'Jane Doe' => 10,
        'Mike Doe' => 10,
        'Gina Doe' => 10,
        'Anne Doe' => 10,
        'George Doe' => 10,
        'Jack Doe' => 10,
    );

    // Create cookie
    setcookie('names', serialize($names), time()+28800);
}

$names = unserialize($_COOKIE['names']);

$randomArray = array();
foreach ($names as $name => $probability) {
    if ($probability > 1) {
        foreach (range(1, $probability) as $v) {
            $randomArray[] = $name;
        }
    } else {
        $names[$name] = 10;
    }
}

$selected = $randomArray[array_rand($randomArray)];
if (array_key_exists($selected, $names)) {
    if ($names[$selected] > 1) {
        $names[$selected]--;
    }
    setcookie('names', serialize($names), time()+28800);
    echo $selected;
}
```

By looking at this code, I guess you'll get the general idea. By making the probability higher, people's name will come up more often.

#### The problem

When the probability comes to 1, I set it back to 10. But somehow this feels wrong. I am not a calculus miracle but my head can figure out that this just isn't right. Also, the piece of code I wrote doesn't feel efficient at all. In my opinion there are too many loops.

What I wold like to ask is for you to take a look at my code and tell me what it is I'm doing wrong and what I can do to improve it. Suggestions etc. are also welcome.

Comment: This should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @lurker I wasn't sure about that. Since there is something about this code that doesn't feel right (something wrong with it) I'm not sure if it is actually a code review.

Comment: If you are having a specific problem, then you'll need to be more precise than "doesn't feel right". If you're getting a specific error, or if you have a result that you are sure isn't right, then you should try to describe that. As it stands, your request is that you want someone to look at your code and suggest improvements. That sounds like code review.

Comment: If you want a recommendation for weighted random selection, Consider the an interval of values which you select random numbers from, and assign weighted percentages for your different selections to that interval by mapping them to specific sub-intervals, for example. But randomness (or pseudo-random in computer programs) is difficult to judge correctness of without generating a very large sample set and measuring frequencies.

Comment: An easy way to do it, if it is acceptable the intern is twice as likely to show up. Is make an array with all the names, the intern twice. And then just pick a random number [0..length-1]. You could of course also just take turns.

Comment: Resetting the probability to 10 probably "doesn't feel right" because you're effectively making the person who's already done it 10 times have a higher probability of having to do it again the next few times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy / lazy approach is to add more instances of the person you want to increase the chance of getting the duty:

```
$names = array(
    'John Doe',
    'Jane Doe',
    'Mike Doe',
    'Gina Doe',
    'Anne Doe',
    'George Doe',
    'Jack Doe',//intern - 50% of getting selected
    'Jack Doe',
    'Jack Doe',
    'Jack Doe',
    'Jack Doe',
    'Jack Doe',
);
var_dump(array_rand($names));
```

#### Edit

So your code is generating the above and you want to simplify it:

```
$names = array(
    'John Doe' => 1,
    'Jane Doe' => 1,
    'Mike Doe' => 2,
    'Gina Doe' => 3,
    'Anne Doe' => 5,
    'George Doe' => 8,
    'Jack Doe' => 13,
);
$randomNames = array();
foreach($names as $name => $probability) {
    do {
        $randomNames[] = $name;
    } while (--$probability > 0);
}
var_dump($randomNames[array_rand($randomNames)]);
```

#### Edit 2

I've just worked out what the COOKIE's are doing. Reducing the probability of each name:

```
session_start();
// instantiate array
$names = array(
    'John Doe' => 1,
    'Jane Doe' => 1,
    'Mike Doe' => 2,
    'Gina Doe' => 3,
    'Anne Doe' => 5,
    'George Doe' => 8,
    'Jack Doe' => 13,
);

// if array exists in session, use that
if(array_key_exists('names',$_SESSION)) {
    $names = unserialize($_SESSION['names']);
}

// Add each name x times where 'x' is the value of $probability
$randomNames = array();
foreach($names as $name => $probability) {
    do {
        $randomNames[] = $name;
    } while (--$probability > 0);
}

// reduce probability by one. If value is less than, or equal to, 0 then reset probability yo 10
$chosen = $randomNames[array_rand($randomNames)];
$names[$chosen]--;
if($names[$chosen] <= 0) {
    $names[$chosen] = 10;
}

// Save array into session for next run
$_SESSION['names'] = serialize($names);

var_dump($chosen,$names);
```

Comment: That's what I am already doing. I add each name multiple times, if I raise $probability for a certain name. The change that name turns up will grow.

Comment: @Peter And you are looking to change the probability by editing a number as opposed to adding/removing names? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the numbers in the array are the weights of probability - even though you've set them all to 10...

So to choose from your array, you need something like...

```
$weight_total = 0;
foreach ($names as $weight) 
  $weight_total += $weight;

$random_number = rand(1, $weight_total); // Random number between 1 and $weight_total

$running_total = 0;
foreach ($names as $name => $weight) {
  if ($random_number > $running_total && $random_number <= ($running_total + $weight)) {
     echo $name; 
     break;
  }
  $running_total += $weight;
}
```

Then just set the intern's weight to be higher than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'd select a random number to determine if it's "the group" or "the poor intern", and if it's "the group", get another random to determince which member of the group.